# how can i extract feature's of gyroscope,accelerometer and magnetomere?

Tags: matlab, accelerometer

I am a new learner about sensors. I have no knowledge about this sensors. However I have done some sensor module which contains with accelerometer,gyroscope and magnetometer. All of them have 3 axis data (X,Y,Z).Now i have data as a TXT file format but I couldn't find any solution for extraction this data features. I am going to use this data with NNet. Could anyone help me with making program in Matlab,please? Any suggestion and opinion will be useful for me. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: People here will help you solving issues with your code, but chance are low that they will do the job for you. How to read data with MATLAB from a text file is documented in the manual.

Comment: @cherouvim: Why did you rollback the tag change?

Comment: @zellus: introducing a tag "do-you-haz-teh-codez" (currently 0 questions) doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: @cherouvim: Do not all tags start by zero?

Comment: @zellus: While funny, tags like that are typically frowned upon as adding very little value.

Comment: To be fair, the OP does ask for suggestions and opinions, and help with making the program - not explicitly for code, even if it may appear at first glance to be such a question.

Answer (score 0):

As zellus suggested, the reading from textfile is well documented in MATLAB. Look for functions textread or csvread.

Comment: hi guys sorry for not explaining well. I have done already matlab code for reading my text file.Now, I am trying to make a program for extracting features from my raw data, this is main problem for me.I have used mean and variance but they are not useful for me. So, I am looking another approaches?

Comment: Not useful for what? What do you want to achieve.

Comment: Because using only mean and variance are not giving satisfactory features, when i use them with Neural Network for classifying activities. As I found out that AutoRegression can be used in this case. So, now i am working with it. I think i can do it by myself. Thanks a lot for your suggestions and opinions.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are looking for help understanding the data that you have collected. You may get some answers here, but you are most likely better off asking what you should be looking for in a physics/engineering related forum, then coming back here for help implementing your code if need be.

As a starting point, you could try:

- [Plotting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) the change in the data over time, for each direction.
- Looking at the magnitude of each of accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer data (using [norm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/norm.html)), and plotting these over time
- Making a [scatter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/scatter.html) plot of the norms of, for example, acceleration vs magnetometer - is there any correlation?
- Likewise a scatter plot of X acceleration vs Y acceleration, or X vs Z etc.

Remember, in MATLAB, the plotting tools are your friend.

Comment: Hi Mr Bill. How are you? Thanks for your comment, I am glad to get a help with you. They are very useful for me.:)